# References side by side instead of 1 in each row

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

Is it possible to have references side by side instead of 1 in each line?
I have space constraint. I am using Overleaf.

This is my bibfile:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm} % Set to Times New Roman
\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\selectfont
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont  % Set font size to 9pt with a 11pt leading (line spacing)
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Ref}
```

I need this style file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.6in, vmargin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "side by side"? Do you just want no line break between the references, so that (effectively) they appear as one big line?

Comment: Yes. Like normal text, line break automatically.

Comment: Just a suggestion: To gain space use  two columns,  narrow fonts, smaller font sizes, less interline space, less margins,  the shortest possible style   (initials instead of full names, abbreviated journal names, etc.) ... whatever except that.